# Equivalent of MATLAB's hold on

Tags: r, matlab, plot

Is there an equivalent of MATLAB's 'hold on' in R? I tried plotting a heatmap and then a dendrogram, but the display of the second figure removes the one of the first. I tried using `par(mfrow)` but it doesn't change the outcome.

Code sample:

```
hc <- hclust(dist_(as.matrix(data)), method="complete")
plot(as.dendrogram(hc),horiz=T,new=TRUE)
heatmap(as.matrix(data), col=heat.colors(length(br)), hclust = hcl_, dist=d_,
        breaks=c(br[1],br), scale="none", Rowv=Rowv, Colv=Colv)
```

Comment: You can add the option `new=TRUE` to the plot command.

Comment: @ilir Actually the same problem happens. I get the dendrogram but then when the heatmap appears it removes the first plot.

Comment: How about `plot(stuff);par(new=TRUE);heatmap(otherstuff)` ?

Comment: Do you mind posting a reproducible example?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft this time only the first graph is displayed

Comment: @ilir I posted a code sample (data is a matrix of examples and features values)

Comment: `new=TRUE` should be on the second plot, to stop it from overwriting the old one. The name is misleading :-)

Comment: @ilir In fact, the heatmap appears some for time but is then replaced by the dendrogram (I plotted the dendrogram after the heatmap since I didn't find a 'new' option on heatmaps)

Comment: @bigTree Any plot function from the base `graphics` library will accept that option. You have not placed any data, so it's impossible to run your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHen I run the following code (note that I'm guessing your `dist_` was a typo),

```
foo<- matrix(runif(400),20)
hc <- hclust(dist(foo), method="complete")
plot(as.dendrogram(hc),horiz=T)
par(new=TRUE)
heatmap(as.matrix(foo), col=heat.colors(10))
```

I get both plots, albeit with the heatmap (and its builtin dendrogram) badly squished to the left. Presumably that can be fixed with some attention to specifying x-axis limits.